# Ancient Greek translation

Tags: greek-translation

I'm not sure where to post this so I thought I would try here. Please let me know if there is a better place for this. I am creating a series of stories and there is some minor connections to nomenclature and myths of ancient Greece. This is a science fiction space series so the title I was looking to use was something along the lines of Stellar Era (age of space/stars). Based on some what I could find that dealt with ancient Greek, I came to: Aera Astrum. 
I hope to make this proper, so is this correct or is there a proper way to phrase this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want something that's purely Greek and then transliterated to the Latin alphabet? Or is it okay to use Latin words too?

Comment: I think I am open to either option. It will be written in English letters in the end anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Expedito's fine answer, you could make it a compound word, which I believe is quite idiomatic in Greek:

**Asteraeon**

This would mean something like "Star-Age".

Comment: Hmm. ἀστεραίων looks weird to me, though I can't quite say why.

Comment: @TKR: I don't know...could it be that αἰὼν is rarely or never used in compounds? I've no idea.

Comment: It has a nice ring to it. I don't know much about Greek, but it sounds legitimate.

Comment: @Cerberus I'm not sure noun-noun compounding of this kind is very productive in Greek.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate it as *Aeon Asteron* (Αἰὼν Ἀστέρων).

According to [LSJ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ai%29w%2Fn&la=greek#lexicon), the Greek word αἰὼν (*aeon*), from which we get the the English word *eon* or *aeon*, has the meaning:

> space of time clearly defined and marked out, epoch, age

The word for [star](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=a%29sth%2Fr&la=greek#lexicon) is ἀστήρ (*aster*). The genitive plural form (= of stars) is ἀστέρων.