# Star age of exploration translation

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation, ancient-greek

A while ago I asked about [a translation for "star age" to ancient Greek](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13453/ancient-greek-translation). I ended up with the wording: Astereaon. I am now curious as to what the translation would be for something like: "The age of star travel / exploration" or "star age exploration". I am unable to find some of these words or base words on some ancient Greek translation websites so I was thinking I could ask that here.

As a note, this is for a series title of a bunch of science fiction stories.
I am also open to a Latin translation of this as both languages /histories play a part in the series.

Comment: If you ended up with *Asteraeon* in the previous question, can you mark that answer as accepted by clicking the green check mark next to the voting arrows? It's helpful to know which answer you found most useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Ἀστρεκδημίας αἰών : Astrekdemias aeon. (Means the age of out-travel to the stars.)
2. Ἀστροκατασκοπῆς αἰών:  Astrokataskopes aeon. (Means the age of star-muster ... the same word used for spying and inspection, though.)

You may transpose the Eon before the qualifier, if you wish.